# СМС с сайта. Как добавить?

Tags: php

Почти на всех сайтах есть регистрация с помощью смс. Как добавить себе на сайт такую функцию?

Comment: Вам нужно найти смс сервис, после зарегистрировать свой сайт у них на сервере, составить шаблоны для смсок, ну а дальше использовать их скрипт для отправки. ПРОФИТ!

Answer (score 1):

1. запрограммировать формирование секртеного числа (типа код 1234)
2. отправить этот код через API клиенту на телефон, например через smsgateway24.com
3. сохранить в базу этот код к этому клиенту
4. когда клиент введет с телефона код, сравнить тот ли он что лежит в базе.
5. если тот - то можно впускать - человек подтвердил валидацию.